# problems compiling TCC on ubuntu for arm

Tags: c, compilation, tcc

I tried to compile tcc for ARM using gcc 4.6.3 . but I got following error while compiling in both shared/static lib mod :

```
root@localhost:/p/tcc/tcc# make
gcc -o tcc tcc.o libtcc.so.1.0 -lm -ldl -Wall -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-sign-compare -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0  -Wl,-rpath,"/usr/local/lib" libtcc.so.1.0: undefined reference to `vrotb'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tcc] Error 1
```

I am using lastest branch from tcc github

Comment: which repository? There are so many forks... Also, what is `uname -a`?

Comment: repo : https://github.com/TinyCC/TinyCC and uname -a : Linux localhost 3.0.89-K^Kernel_JB-4.1.2_OC_UV_370MB+ #2 PREEMPT Mon Aug 5 00:42:04 CEST 2013 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: It seems ok. Could you run `make clean`, `./configure` then `make` and provide it's full output?

Comment: here you are : http://paste.lisp.org/+2ZJW

Comment: It appears some change in this branch have broken compatibility with arm. In tccgen.c:945 remove 'static' qualifier, this should help you. Or try this repo https://github.com/LuaDist/tcc not sure which one is newer, but they surely different.

Comment: I could compile from LuaDist githuh sucessfully but the output tcc can not compile a helloworld program . also 'make test' fails

Comment: Finally managed to test it in real environment, so added answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just checked it on raspberry pi (ARMv6 CPU). https://github.com/TinyCC/TinyCC repository, removed `static` qualifier from `vrotb` function in tccgen.c (line 945). It builds and passes 'hello world'.

Since that's obvious mistake likely to be introduced by some change that they forgot to adapt for ARM - i suggest performing further tests to ensure it works as intended. Bug report should be filed - probably on github.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is little confusing, but your problem is that you are using wrong repository. Fabrice Bellard does not work any more on TinyCC (see http://bellard.org/tcc/). He keeps his repositories for personal/historical reasons. However all development has moved to http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git. To confuse things even more the 0.9.26 release from Fabrice's web site is actually from the http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git repository, and not Fabrice's own. But this is all just communication issue. In short you should use new repository. On the repository web site is a link to a mailing list where you should report any problems in case the new repo code does not compile.

Comment: This is the answer. I'm so stupid trying to fix something that isn't broken.. :-)